# Port Forwarding An Linux IP In Virtualbox ISSUES

Tags: linux, virtualbox, portforwarding

Here's The Scoop,

I used SET (Social Engineering Toolkit) and made duplicite of a login page, the ip that was used was 10.0.2.15 (Mind you this is on a virtual machine Virtualbox), and when I tried to view it on another computer, it says the server is not responding.I tried to port forward but it was giveing me issues.
is there anything I can do to port forward or do something like that to make the web page connected to the IP viewable on the World Wide Web of another computer.

In other words, the IP's page is only viewable on the same computer who's ip I used to host, can you make it viewable on any computers browser by port forwarding it or something that will work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use bridging networking for the guest machine. Then, that IP address should be accessible on your network if there are no firewalls enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with directly accessing this IP from a separate computer.

First, the forwarding: the computer with the VirtualMachine must accept ip forwarding. This is easy to enable:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing

Second, the routing: other computers must know who to ask when looking for 10.0.2.15. This is the hardest part. You could try adding a special route rule on the other computer, to set the host as a gateway for 10.0.2.15, but it requires you to make this on every machine that wishes to access the VM.

As Ahmed said, the easiest way is probably to use a network bridge, where the virtual machine will act as any other computer on the network, with a visible IP.